# Generating change given a cash amount and a list of currency

Tags: prolog, coin-change

I'm trying to write a program in Prolog, that does two things:

1. Takes two arguments, an integer and a list of integers
2. Is satisfied if change for the first argument can be made from some combination of elements from the second

I have come up with a solution to this problem that allows a change rule to unify to coin facts, as such:

```
coin(quarter, 25).
coin(dime,10).
coin(nickel,5).
coin(penny,1).

change(0, []).
change(A, [(C, Num)|L]) :- 
    coin(C, V), 
    A >= V, 
    Num is floor(A / V), 
    B is A mod V, 
    change(B, L).
```

Additionally, if you pass something like change(27,L) to the interpreter, it generates all possible combinations of quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies that can be used to make change, like such:

```
?- change(27,L).
L = [(quarter, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
L = [(dime, 2),  (nickel, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
L = [(dime, 2),  (penny, 7)] ;
L = [(nickel, 5),  (penny, 2)] ;
L = [(penny, 27)] ;
false.
```

I'm having trouble, however, with how this can be solved by simply passing a currency list like [25,10,5,1] into change, making the call look something like change(27, [25,10,5,1], L). Is this possible and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: Not the same problem. I'm trying to generate change without a limit on the amount of each coin type available and for any amount.

Comment: You're right. It should be something like change(27, [25,10,5,1] , L).

Comment: Yes, change(27,[25,10,5,1], L). is the right one. This is not homework.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt a program that was originally written in Standard ML, so the instructions aren't exact.

Comment: Yes, that is also correct. The list does not need the name of the coin, just the coins necessary to make the change, like change(27, [25,10,5,1] , L) could just return [25,1,1] or [10,10,5,1,1].

Comment: It would be conventional to use a parameter (let's call it `Coinage`) like `[quarter=25, dime=10, nickel=5, penny=1]` as your argument, and then just change `coin(C, V)` to `member(C=V, Coinage)`.

Comment: so you have `[ (10, 2), (5, 1), (1, 2) ]` among the results, but `[ (10, 1), (5, 3), (1, 2) ]` is also a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're actually quite close. This is basically the comment I left, expanded. Let's add another argument for the types of coinage.

```
change(0, _, []).
change(A, Coinage, [(C, Num)|L]) :- 
    member(C=V, Coinage), 
    A >= V, 
    Num is floor(A / V), 
    B is A mod V, 
    change(B, Coinage, L).
```

I have replaced `coin(C, V)` with this `member(C=V, Coinage)` term. `member/2` is a great way to make your Prolog program more dynamic, because rather than consulting the fact store, you can essentially generate solutions out of a list. Take a look at the result:

```
?- change(27, [quarter=25, dime=10, nickel=5, penny=1], Change).
Change = [(quarter, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(dime, 2),  (nickel, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(dime, 2),  (penny, 7)] ;
Change = [(nickel, 5),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(penny, 27)] ;
false.
```

Let's see if we should add a 3-cent coin, perhaps with a recent president's face on it:

```
?- change(27, [quarter=25, dime=10, nickel=5, thripenny=3, penny=1], Change).
Change = [(quarter, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(dime, 2),  (nickel, 1),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(dime, 2),  (thripenny, 2),  (penny, 1)] ;
Change = [(dime, 2),  (penny, 7)] ;
Change = [(nickel, 5),  (penny, 2)] ;
Change = [(thripenny, 9)] ;
Change = [(penny, 27)] ;
```

Looks like it would be a great idea!

Comment: Thanks! This does what I want. As I mentioned, I'm trying to pick up Prolog from Standard ML. Since there is no fact base in this solution, does this mean that Prolog is not "unifying" anything?

Comment: @JoshB No, unification is happening whenever Prolog binds a value to a variable. In the sequence `member(C=V, Coinage), A >= V`, Prolog will unify C=quarter, V=25 first. Then it will attempt A >= V. If A is less than V, it will fail, backtrack, and then retry the member call with C=dime, V=10. (Really, it is unifying `C=V` with `quarter=25`, but unification is recursive on the structure of the term.)